# How to search within a specific hubsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, hub-site

Using either Search Query tool or modern search WebParts (SPFx), is it possible to filter results from a specific hub site or site in a hub site ?

In the search query tool *view all properties* dialog, I don't see any managed property that suggest this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, quite simply actually.

Thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/issues/136), I found that the `DepartmentId` corresponds to the hub site.

So, this KQL filters on the hub site :

```
DepartmentId:"{24af7e54-d2f9-422d-a44e-6a6d40077d50}"
```

or (no more working)

```
DepartmentId:"{Site.ID}"
```

or (credits to @Alberto)

```
DepartmentId:{{PageContext.hubSiteId}}
```

if from a web-part.

Comment: I am trying to use the current site ID in my search query, but it doesnt work... any idea/suggestion? DepartmentId:{{Site.ID}} {searchTerms}

Comment: You have double {{ and }} .... is it a typo ?

Comment: I tried with double {{ and single {, but never got it to work. Can you confirm that if I run such KQL sentence, it will perform the search filtering results by DepartmentId={current site ID} ( in order to perform searches from the central hubsite itself ). thanks

Comment: I use this syntax without issue. Can you describe what happens ? No result ? erro r?

Comment: Didnt work for me, however, I could use this other param DepartmentId:{{PageContext.hubSiteId}}, tahnks Steve ;)

Comment: @Alberto, today, I face the same issue you describe. it may have changed from a previous version of the component ? As a workaround, you can still manually specify the id

Comment: I confirm u that another workaround is to just use DepartmentId:{{PageContext.hubSiteId}}, it works as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Tip. If you're using PnP Modern Search Solution V4, you need to escape the curly braces.

You can escape curly braces characters using '' to avoid: ex: DepartmentId:{edbfd618-ef1d-4cc5-a214-95bf44ddf4ee}

https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/tokens/